# How do you reset the BIOS password on a Lenovo ThinkCentre m910q workstation?

Tags: bios, lenovo

Lenovo's stock documentation applies to all of their ThinkCentre computers, so it's pretty vague. It indicates that a jumper needs to be moved but doesn't indicate which one. The hardware and maintenance manual for the unit does not contain any info on this.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the same spot as the M710Q. If you remove the cover, and hold it with the rear ports at the top, it's the jumper in the upper-left corner. It has to be moved down from the top two pins to the bottom two pins, on the left side.

See this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQKVUzjMozE